# Repo still uses 8 GB of quota after force push to initial commit (empty repo)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-gc

- My gitlab repo was ~8GO
- To rewrite it completely with size optimisation the idea was to reset the remote to the first commit and force push (`git checkout <initial hash>; git push -f`)
- Then rewrite the history locally reducing size with compression and LFC, then force push again.

The issue is that after doing `git checkout <initial hash>; git push -f` the quota used on the repo remotely is still 8GO (and so I am not able to push the history as 8+X > Quota).

What can I do to make gitlab reprocess the quota ?
I triggered the warehousing but without any result.

The expected result is: quota 1ko (initial commit)

Comment: If you're going to remove everything from this repo, it's simplest to delete it and start a brand new one from scratch. Of course, you'd like the issues and other meta data too, so this might not be what you want to do...

Comment: Does the section with the title "Repository cleanup" in the manual help? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html#repository-cleanup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab holds onto refs in hidden areas that are not advertised. Therefore, even force-pushing to advertised refs will not shrink the repository size. In order to actually reduce repository storage used, you'll need to follow the procedure for [purging files from repository history](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html#purge-files-from-repository-history).